# Using "Wenn" in the Past

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

Is it possible to use *wenn* when referring to the past? I've researched that *wenn* is used exclusively for the present and future, while *als* is used for the past.

For example, I was trying to figure out how to say

> When I had a lot of homework to do, I was irritated.
>   Wenn ich viele Hausaufgaben habe, mache ich geärgert.

How would I say that in proper German?

Comment: "jemandem Ärger machen" (to cause trouble), but "verärgert sein" (to be irritated). Also you switched into present tense for your translation.

Comment: When und wenn sind false friends. Sie klingen gleich, aber das engl. when ist im Deutschen als, das deutsche wenn ist ein if auf Englisch. Ein Wörterbuch sollte diese Frage beantworten können.

Comment: @userunknown Nicht immer. Sehr wohl kann man den obigen Satz übersetzen zu *(Immer)Wenn ich viele Hausaufgaben hatte, war...*.

Comment: Stimmt. Aber natürlich "hatte", nicht "habe". Und ich würde dennoch spontan "als" wählen, und "wenn" eher bei "if".

Comment: @userunknown *Als* würde ich aber auf ein einzelnes Ereignis beziehen, *wenn* jedoch auf alle möglichen Ereignisse (daher würde ich es dann auch mit *immer wenn* übersetzen). Die Frage, ob man jetzt *als* oder *immer wenn* nehmen muss, würde sich aus dem Kontext ergeben. Im obigen Kontext würde ich *immer wenn* nehmen.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Ich weiß nicht wo Du da ein immer hernimmst. Es könnte sichgenausogut auf ein singuläres Ereignis beziehen.

Comment: Könnte, ja. Ohne Kontextinfo darf ich mir aber was aussuchen. Normalerweise gilt die Regel, dass if mit wenn/falls und when mit wenn/als übersetzt wird. Das letztere wie gesagt in Abhängigkeit vom Kontext, je nachdem ob häufiges/regelmäßiges Ereignis oder einmaliges.

Answer (score 6):

```
Wenn ich viele Hausaufgaben hatte, war ich immer ärgerlich.
```

The rule you quote is not exactly right. What matters is the *habitual aspect*, not whether the described events are in the past or in the future. As a rule of thumb, whenever you use 'whenever' (rather than just 'when') in English, you can use 'wenn' or 'immer wenn' in German.

(A difference exists for the conditional or temporal sense: future situations prefer 'wenn' and past situations prefer 'als', but your example is definitely a case of habitual aspect.)

Comment: Wo kommt das Wort »immer« her?

Comment: Und "irritated" ist "ärgerlich"?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Eingefügt, um die Bedeutung "regelmäßig, wenn" im Gegensatz zu "falls" zu betonen. In einer alleinstehenden Übersetzung würde man es nicht verwenden, aber die Frage geht um "Wie benutzt man das wort 'wenn'?" und nicht "Please translate this sentence for me" (reine Übersetzungsanfragen sind off-topic).

Comment: As a German, you would not phrase it that way: *"Ärgerlich"* refers to the thing that you are annoyed/irritated *about*, as in "Einen Fehler zu machen ist ärgerlich". For the original sentence, one would rather say *"...war ich immer verärgert"*. Apart from that, "verärgert" IMHO corresponds being *annoyed*. In the given example, saying something like *"...war ich immer genervt"* could be more appropriate (but it may sound less formal, and is just my gut feeling).

Answer (score 1):

The original and your translation don't match here, starting with my impression that the English sentence *When I had a lot of homework to do, I was irritated* is not clear. That is because it is in the past and lacking a context. So, two kinds of translations seem possible:

> Es störte mich (immer), *wenn* ich viele Hausaufgaben zu erledigen
>   hatte. (conditional clause)

als auch:

> *Als* ich (einmal) viele Hausaufgaben zu erledigen hatte, ärgerte mich
>   das. (temporal clause)

However, the first version would rather assume a phrasing like "I used to be irritated when I had a lot of homework to do".

As soon as you put the English original into present tense, it becomes clear what should be the proper translation:

> *Wenn* ich viele Hausaufgaben habe, stört mich das.

Thus, keep in mind as a rule of thumb:

```
When (conditional) = Wenn
When (temporal) = Als
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncertain, this rule of thumb may work:

"Als" can be used when referring to "that one time" a more or less precise time, for example: "Als ich ein Kind war"

Wenn can be used in the other cases more or less. Be careful that for indirect questions "wann" should be used instead.